# JavaScript String variable not updating

Tags: javascript

I have a var `word_matching` this variable should is used for storing a string of HTML. The problem is that the string is not getting updated:

```
if(!htmlGenerated)
{
  word_matching.innerHTML = '';
  console.log("generating textarea");
  // create textarea
  word_matching.innerHTML = '<textarea id="html" value=';
  console.log(word_matching.innerHTML);
  // create key inputs
  for (let i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++)
  {
    word_matching.innerHTML += '<div id="s'+i+'"class="draggyBox-small">'+elArray[i]+'</div>\n' 
  }
  
  // create description inputs
  for (let i = 0; i < dlArray.length; i++)
  {
    word_matching.innerHTML += '<table id="tablestyle"><td >\n \t\t<div id="t'+i+'"class="ltarget"></div>\n \t</td >\n \t<td  id="d2">'+dlArray[i]+'</td >\n </tr>\n</table>'
  }

  word_matching.innerHTML += '<div id = "program1" style="border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;"> <span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="one()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button><button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id = "audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"/> </a> </span> </span> </div> </div></div>">';
  htmlGenerated = true;
  console.log("________ word matching _________");
  console.log(word_matching.innerHTML);
  console.log("________ word matching _________");  
}
```

everything after the second initialization works. The code below prints out a blank line

```
//  create textarea
word_matching.innerHTML = '<textarea id="html" value=';
console.log(word_matching.innerHTML);
```

The code below

```
console.log("________ word matching _________");
console.log(word_matching.innerHTML);
console.log("________ word matching _________");
```

prints out

```
________ word matching _________
Section5_3.html:131 
<div id="s0" class="draggyBox-small">k1</div>
<div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small">k2</div>
  <table id="tablestyle">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="t0" class="ltarget"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d2">d1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="tablestyle">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="t1" class="ltarget"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d2">d2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<div id="program1" style="border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;"> <span style="padding: 3px"> <button id="one" class="button" type="button" onclick="one()">Show Answer</button> <button id="resetButton" class="button" type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button><button id="renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onclick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id="audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"> </a> </span> </span> </div> "&gt;
________ word matching _________
```

I've tried printing out the line. Is there an error in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//has the html already been generated? 
      if(!htmlGenerated){

        //create textarea
        textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        
        // initialize blank html
        html = '';

        //create key inputs
        for (let i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++){
          html += '<div id="s';
          html +=i;
          html +='\" class=\"draggyBox-small\">';
          html += elArray[i];
          html +='</div>\n';
        }
  
        //create description inputs
        html += '<table id=\"tablestyle\"><td >\n'
        for (let i = 0; i < dlArray.length; i++){
          html += '\t\t<div id=\"t';
          html +=i;
          html +='" class=\"ltarget\"></div>\n \t</td >\n \t<td  id=\"d2\">'
          html +=dlArray[i];
          html +='</td >\n </tr>\n';
        }
        html += '</table>';

        // html generation is done.
        htmlGenerated = true;
        
        textarea.value = html;
        results.appendChild(textarea);

        // Generate reset, show answer, , and render html buttons
        controls = document.createElement("div");
        controls.setAttribute("id","program1");
        controls.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        controls.innerHTML +=  '<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="one()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button><button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button> <span id = "audio" style=""> <a href="" title="Turns Text-to-Speech Output On or Off" class="menulink" style="text-decoration: none;"><img id="bg" src="audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;"/> </a> </span> </span>';
       results.appendChild(controls);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your statement creates an incorrect html template. This will not be set to set as `innerHTML` as the template is incorrect.

```
word_matching.innerHTML = '<textarea id="html" value=';
```

Try setting some valid html template for example

```
word_matching.innerHTML = '<textarea id="html" value="test"></textarea>';
```

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const word_matching = document.getElementById("word_matching");

word_matching.innerHTML = '<textarea id="html" value=';
// This wont work
console.log(word_matching.innerHTML);

word_matching.innerHTML = '<textarea id="html" value="test"></textarea>';
// This will work
console.log(word_matching.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="word_matching"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery land answer would be as below:

```
jQuery(function() {
let word = $('#word-matching')
word.html('whatever you'd like the HTML to be')
})

HTML
<div id="word-matching"></div>
```

It's important to note you should use an ID when using .html as it will replace the HTML contents in all selectors which in most cases you will not want.